# parent view's name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial View used in many pages and I was wondering if there was a way to obtain the name of the Parent View that contains my Partial View currently?

Comment: Can you see if any of these properties have what you want? `ViewUserControl.Page`, `ViewUserControl.Parent` or `ViewUserControl.Url` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the controller and action from the PartialView:

```
<%=ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] %>

<%=ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] %>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

You can also look at the `ViewPath` if it would help:

```
<%= (ViewContext.View as WebFormView).ViewPath %>
```

Comment: Those give access to controller and action names, not a view name. `ViewPath` gives the name of the view, but of the current view, not of the parent.

Comment: Old answers may still have room for improvement. I often pick up as much useful information from comments as from answers, so I comment. The facts are still relevant.