# Calling same partial view from multiple parent pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view which I am using in 2 parent pages. I want to detect from which parent page I am calling that partial view.

Does there is any event to find this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parent view's name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902373/parent-views-name)

Answer (score 0):

The `PartialExtensions.Partial` helper has an extension that takes a ViewDataDictionary as well the partial name, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407439(v=vs.100).aspx. You can use this to pass in whatever you want as key:value pairs, e.g. ParentViewName as a string. So from the parent views you can do

```
@Html.Partial("PartialName", new ViewDataDictionary { {"ParentViewName", "ParentView1"} })
```

Then in your partial you can access that view data via:

```
@ViewData["ParentViewName"]
```